# xUnit.net equivalent for TestContext.AddResultFile()

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

When using MSTest, I believe it's possible to add result files that will appear as attachments in the build reports in TFS (we're using 2015 FWIW), using

```
TestContext.AddResultFile("filename");
```

Is there an way of doing this if we're using xUnit.net, short of switching back to MSTest or another test framework?

Comment: xUnit certainly doesnt have direct support of this nature - chances are in VS2012+ such stuff is handled by the VS-side infrastructure. You should be able to work out where it lives by taking ILSpy to the MSTest dll?

Comment: @MJF Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I have posted recently here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949301/how-to-duplicate-mstest-attachment-functionality-with-xunit

Comment: I was also looking for this feature but found out that the issue was closed for some time now on the xUnit github: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/936.